Upgrading ASP.NET MVC from .NET 4.6 to .NET 8 with SharePoint On-Premises Authentication (ADFS)
I'm working on upgrading an existing ASP.NET MVC application from .NET 4.6 to .NET 8. The application currently uses SharePoint on-premises for document management, and ADFS handles user authentication.
Challenge: the library we're using for SharePoint authentication, OfficeDevPnP.Core.IdentityModel.TokenProviders.ADFS, is no longer supported. Since PnP Framework focuses on SharePoint Online, I'm unsure of the best approach for on-premises authentication in .NET 8.
Question: what are the recommended approaches for on-premise SharePoint authentication in .NET 8?
